# JPA queries for write operation on postgresql database taking too much time intermittently

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I have connected my postgresql database with my spring boot project. I have observed that when I do any write (save or update) operation first time on my database with repo call of JPA, it takes around 10 secs. but I do next time save or update call, it takes around 150ms. and If I try this same next day then first call takes too long time than next calls.

I am trying to reduce time of first call in miliseconds.

Comment: Do you have a connection pool for your datasource?  It sounds as if it's having to create a new database connection after some idle period.  Consider adjusting the `minimumIdle` property to something like 5 or set the `idleTimeout` to a very large value.

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on the DB first thing the next day in order to help isolate the issue? You may want to share your DB configuration information as well.

Comment: Connection pool seems likely, but there are many settings and potential causes - If you have too many connections in the pool and they are killed by a firewall or timeout for lack of use, when you try to get a connection it'll take more time as the pool goes through each to find one that is still valid - and then spins up more when it can't. You will want to performance tune your connection pool and ensure the keep alives, idle times and the number of connections are reasonable for your application, and that there aren't network issues like firewalls contributing to delays

Comment: @lane.maxwell how can we increase minimumIdle time

Comment: @Hareesh Set the property `spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle` to a value greater than 0 (like 5?).  It's defined as a primitive `int` in the `HikariConfig`, which means it defaults to 0.